# Configuring the Swagger codegen with Gradle. How does the provided Gradle script work?

Tags: gradle, swagger, gradle-plugin, swagger-codegen

I am doing battle with this code here: https://github.com/thebignet/swagger-codegen-gradle-plugin-example

Trying to build a REST client using Swagger codegen and Gradle. I am new to Gradle and looking at this example is quite confusing as there are multiple variables / properties / names that I have no clue where they come from or what they do. Especially this part:

```
clean.doFirst {
    delete(swaggerOutputDir)
}

configurations {
    swagger
}

sourceSets {
    swagger {
        compileClasspath = configurations.swaggerCompile
        java {
            srcDir file("${project.buildDir.path}/swagger/src/main/java")
        }
    }
    main {
        compileClasspath += swagger.output
        runtimeClasspath += swagger.output
    }
    test {
        compileClasspath += swagger.output
        runtimeClasspath += swagger.output
    }
}

compileSwaggerJava.dependsOn generateApi
classes.dependsOn swaggerClasses
compileJava.dependsOn compileSwaggerJava
```

**swagger.output** - where this comes from?

**classes, compileJava, swaggerClasses, compileSwaggerJava**
What are all of those? They don't seem to be defined anywhere and seem to be randomly named?

Then the readme says: 
In order to generate Swagger source code, launch the following task.
generateApi : generate Swagger code

Where the hell are **Swagger** and **code** coming from?

Any clarifications are much appreciated and I believe will help a lot more people.

Comment: "clean.doFirst { delete(swaggerOutputDir)  }" is from another block of code in your provided link. I would suggest either removing it or providing the whole extra block of code. (it just makes sure that the output dir is empty so that you don't have any generated sources from previous procedures)

Answer (score 10):

To fully understand this code, you have to read through the [Gradle DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/dsl/index.html) (domain-specific-language)

- A [SourceSet](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html):

> A SourceSet represents a logical group of Java source and resources.

Inside the block sourceSets{ }, a new SourceSet `swagger` is defined.

In the above link to the SourceSet's definition, you will notice that since `swagger` is now a SourceSet, it has the property 'output' which provides all the output directories of this SourceSet: thus, you can call `swagger.output`

In every Gradle Java project, there is the assumption there are main sources and test sources. This assumption is introduced by the [`java`](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/java_plugin.html#java_plugin) plugin, which is required for Gradle to process Java. (This standardized layout stems from the [Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).) You configure those source sets through `main{}` and `test{}`. Of course, you may have more source sets.
What `compileClasspath += swagger.output` and `runtimeClasspath += swagger.output` does, is add the swagger-generated code (or any swagger output in general) in their compile-time and runtime classpath directory. Since swagger does code generation, this is expected behavior.

- Now, about [Gradle Tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html):

> A Task represents a single atomic piece of work for a build, such as compiling classes or generating javadoc.

The java plugin mentioned above, when creating a new SourceSet, creates also some [associated tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/java_plugin.html#java_source_set_tasks): `compileSourceSetJava`, `processSourceSetResources` and `sourceSetClasses` (replacing SourceSet with each SourceSet's name). That's what those `compileSwaggerJava`, `swaggerClasses` are, the generated tasks from the `swagger` SourceSet.
For the standard sourcesets, those tasks [are](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_tasks):
*main sourceset's tasks:* `compileJava`, `processResources`, `classes`
*test sourceset's tasks:* `compileTestJava`, `processTestResources`, `testClasses`

> A task may have dependencies on other tasks or might be scheduled to always run after another task.

This is configured through the task's [properties](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#N18AFE). One of those, is the `dependsOn` property which explains this last block of your provided code.
(Note: the generateApi task in the last block of code, is defined in the link the OP shared in the question)

Comment: Thanks a lot tryman! Very good information! I still don't understand the last part though. That generateApi : generate Swagger code. I understand where generateApi task is defined, but what are generate and code parameters? Could you, please, update your answer with that?

Comment: @BorisHamanov I think the task call is just the "generateApi" part and and the rest is just an explanation that what it does is "generate Swagger code". If it's indeed that, it is very badly phrased, I got confused as well. One and a half years later still didn't have time to test this, but I see this this blog [post](https://blog.jcore.com/2017/05/automatically-generating-your-api-from-a-swagger-file-using-gradle/) and it seems to be just "generateApi"